# Pocketsphinx for android install on windows

Tags: windows, android-studio, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

Where can I find a step-by-step solution for my problem? I saw the demo, I checked the tutorial. I couldn't find find jar or aar file. I've downloaded tar folder, I cannot run any files in there with my visual studio, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Jar file can be imported in the Android Studio. Aar can be downloaded from github. Also found good articles:

1. https://www.guidearea.com/pocketsphinx-continuous-speech-recognition-android-tutorial/
2. http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html